# Data extraction using powershell, CSV file extract to have column header when 0 rows in sql server table.

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am extracting sql server table data to csv file. When there are no rows, I still need column headers. Below code only returns blank file.

```
$queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$viewfilename] "
#Specify the output location of your dump file
$extractFile = "$filepath\DATA\ $viewfilename.csv"
$command.CommandText = $queryData
$command.Connection = $connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi, why would the headers be useful if there is no data?

Comment: @sodawillow, some tools throw an error when trying to read an empty .csv file. Example: Python Pandas

Answer (score 2):

Change you "$DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation" to this code:

```
if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
  $header = ""
    foreach ($col in $DataSet.Tables[0].Columns) {
        $header += $col.ColumnName +","
    }
    $header.Remove($header.Length-1,1) | Out-File $extractFile
} else {
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Michael Kunznetsov's answer, we're going to check if there are any rows that exist, and if not we'll just add a blank row. Then output the table, and one way or another you'll have a file either full of data, or with one blank entry. This takes a few cycles out of things for you, since we don't have to loop through columns, as creating a new row is based off of the DataTable schema and will include all column headers.

```
if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
    $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add($DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow())
}
$DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
```

If the blank entry really bothers you, and you only want the headers you can make things a little more complicated by adding the row, then converting to a CSV, selecting only the first line, and saving that to a file. That would look more like:

```
if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
    $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add($DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow())
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -First 1 | Set-Content $extractFile
}Else{
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

This would make sure that you have properly formatted CSV files in case you have headers with spaces or commas in them.