# Powershell's Export-CSV command not including header (column names) when there are no results

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd, export-csv

I have a CSV file that is used as a resource by other files. It is expected that this CSV file will always have a header row at the very minimum which specifies the expected columns. Not having this header row causes errors in the other files.

In my situation I will have some occasions where there are no results but I still need the header row. Does anyone know how to force this header row to be written to the CSV file even if there are no results?

Here is the gist of the command.

```
Set-Location c:

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE my;" -ServerInstance "myserver.fake" -Database "db" -Username "user" -Password "password" -Querytimeout 65535 | Export-Csv -Path "\\MyDirectory\MyResults.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data extraction using powershell, CSV file extract to have column header when 0 rows in sql server table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053469/data-extraction-using-powershell-csv-file-extract-to-have-column-header-when-0)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) and [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) for their help.</sup>

**Create the CSV header row *manually*, using *plain-text processing***.

The following assumes that the output CSV file path is stored in variable `$outFile`:

```sh
if ((Get-Item -LiteralPath $outFile).Length -eq 0) { # Nothing was exported.

  # Define the array of column names.
  # Ideally, these should come from a different SQL query
  # that returns the column names of MY_TABLE.
  $columnNames = 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'

  # Transform the to a CSV header line and write to the target file.
  $columnNames.ForEach({ "`"$_`"" }) -join "," |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile

}
```

Note:

- If the query targets only a *single* table / view, as in your example, you can obtain its column names via `Read-SqlTableData` / `Read-SqlViewData`, as shown in the next section.

The above stores the following in the output file, if it was found to be empty after exporting (due to the query returning no rows):

```sh
"Foo","Bar","Baz"
```

---

**A solution limited to reading data *from a single table* (unconditionally, though the count of rows can be limited), using [`Read-SqlTableData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata)** (or, analogously, using [`Read-SqlViewData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqlviewdata) for a single *view*):<sup>[1]</sup>

If you pass `-OutputAs DataTable` (or `-As DataTable`) to a `Read-SqlTableData` call, it will return a [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows) instance, which provides access to not just the table's *data* (rows, via `.Rows`), but also the *table structure* (column names, via `.Columns.ColumnName`).

- Note: Regrettably, even though [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) also supports `-OutputAs DataTables` (note the plural `s`, though), it returns *nothing* rather than a `DataTable` instance if the query happens to return no rows.

```sh
# Get table MY_TABLE as a DataTable instance.
$dataTable = 
  Read-SqlTableData -OutputAs DataTable -TableName MY_TABLE -ServerInstance "myserver.fake" -Database "db" -Username "user" -Password "password" -Querytimeout 65535

if ($dataTable.Rows.Count -gt 0) {  # At least 1 row found, export it.

  $dataTable.Rows | Export-Csv -Path "\\MyDirectory\MyResults.csv" -NoTypeInformation

} else { # No query results - write the header row (only).

  # Create the header row manually, using plain-text processing.
  $dataTable.Columns.ColumnName.ForEach({ "`"$_`"" }) -join "," |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile

}
```

---

<sup>[1] As Bacon Bits points out, there's really no good reason for *separate* cmdlets to support tables vs. views.</sup>

Comment: @BaconBits, thanks for the heads-up - please see my update.